# Divide an audio signal into discrete samples in java

Tags: java, audio

I have no experience in sound processing with java.I'm trying to process an audio signal and divide it into N discrete samples. Can anyone provide me with an easy, well explained code?
The codes given in internet for sound processing are a bit complex.

Comment: A digital audio signal is already divided into discrete samples. The number of time divisions per second is called the sample rate. Are you trying to further sub-divide it?

Comment: yes, i am trying to do so

Comment: Then what you are looking for is called sample rate conversion. One java library I found by googling is called FMJ and a wrapper around a command line tool called ffmpeg.